# settings to get 500 error on browsing sitecore/shell

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Currently on browsing sitecore/shell, I am getting 401 Error.

I want to get 500 error for this. What setting on sitecore folder or change in config file can help in this?

Comment: 401 means unauthorized. 500 indicates a server error. Why do you want to give the false impression of an error?

Comment: @Martin On one environment I am getting 401 and on other 500. I am not getting what setting is giving this error.

Comment: The environment returning a 500 response has an error. You should check the Sitecore logs to find out what it is.